# Angulajs: Share http response with all pages without loading 2nd time

Tags: angularjs, http

I hope this thread finds everyone healthy.

My app has 2 pages and i am using same controller for both pages.

I am doing a dozen of http requests at page load and share the data with both pages. but each time i visit one of the pages all the http requests are sent to server again. 
How can i request server only 1 time and share the data between pages.

I tried to create a factory for one of http requests but still the request is sent each time i visit one of the pages.

My Code:

```
App.controller('mainController', function ($scope, translation) {

//methos 1
     $http.get('types/').
        success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            $scope.types = data;
        });

//methos 2
  translation.list(function(tr) {
        $scope.trans = tr;
  });

}

App.factory('translation', function ($http) {
  return {
    list: function (callback) {
        $http.get('trans/').success(callback);
    }
};
```

});

What i am doing wrong here?

Comment: You have a couple options.  1: Resolve the data in your route config or 2: Return promises

Comment: or cache it e.g. `$http.get(url, { cache: true }).success(...);`

Comment: Or using a service that proxy the call. When you "get" from factory it return a parameter or do a call depending on if the value is already set or not.

Comment: @Rob I am loading large data... will resolving data in route config make page load any slower?

Comment: When loading large data you can add a spinner until the data is loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Heres is an example:

```
App.factory('translation', function ($http,$q) {
  var types_q = $q.defer();
  var service = {
    types: [],
    list: list
  }

  return service;

  function list() {
      if (!service.types.length) {
        console.log('fetching from server...');
        $http.get('trans/').then(function(response) {
          service.types = response.data.types;
          types_q.resolve(response);
        });
      }

      return $q.when('types_q').then(function() {
        return types_q.promise;
      });
  }
});

App.controller('mainController', function ($scope, translation) {

  $scope.loading = true;

  translation.list().then(function(response) {
    $scope.types = response.data.types;
    $scope.loading = false;
  });

});
```